# Creating F# record through reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

How can I create a record type in F# by using reflection? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why do you need specifically records?

Comment: @Giuseppe: I updated my answer with an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`FSharpValue.MakeRecord`<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353790.aspx) to create a record instance, but I don't think there's anything baked into F# for defining record *types*. However, records compile to simple classes, so you could build a class as you would in C#. [`TypeBuilder`<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) may be a good starting point.

#### UPDATE

Adding `[<CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.RecordType)>]` to the type is all that's required to make it a record. Here's an example of how to do this at run-time.

```
let asmName = AssemblyName("Foo")
let asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect)
let moduleBldr = asm.DefineDynamicModule("Test")
let typeBldr = moduleBldr.DefineType("MyRecord", TypeAttributes.Public)
let attrBldr = CustomAttributeBuilder(
                typeof<CompilationMappingAttribute>.GetConstructor([|typeof<SourceConstructFlags>|]), 
                [|box SourceConstructFlags.RecordType|])
typeBldr.SetCustomAttribute(attrBldr)
let typ = typeBldr.CreateType()
printfn "%b" <| FSharpType.IsRecord(typ) //true
```

Comment: I have built a TypeBuilder already, but I would like to create a quotation that uses Expr.NewRecord with a System.Type I have built; do I need a special type to invoke Expr.NewRecord?

Comment: @GiuseppeMaggiore I think the type may need to be marked with a special attribtue (and possibly also have the exact form as the records generated by F# compiler). Did you look at the type that F# generates using ILSpy/Reflector (I'm sure they are marked with some attribute, but there may be also something in the resources, which would be difficult to do yourself)?

Comment: @Tomas: Any idea why there isn't an `FSharpType.MakeRecordType` given that there are `MakeTupleType` and `MakeFunctionType` methods?

Comment: @Daniel I think that's because making a tuple or function type involves just creating `System.Type` that represents some combination of existing types (`Tuple` and `FSharpFunc`), but generating a record actually involves emitting a type using reflection (which is more complex and there are more options, like in what assembly to put the type in...)

Comment: BTW: +1 for actually implementing it :-)