# Creating record type in F#

Tags: f#, type-providers

I would like to craft a simple record type based on fields provided.

That is :

```
let rectype = MakeRecordType(['fieldname1'; 'fieldname2'])
```

Going directly to type providers looks like heavy gunpower for such a simple task.

Are there any other way ?

*update*

I found the following question which look very similar
[Creating F# record through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139223/creating-f-record-through-reflection)

Comment: I don't understand, how would you use a record type that was otherwise dynamically created? As opposed to: `type MyRecord = { field1: string, field2: string}`

Comment: @yamen I would use it pretty much the same way as any other type.

Comment: What I mean is - if you're providing a dynamic list of properties, are you then using them dynamically or statically? If statically, why not define it statically in the first place.

Comment: I use it dynamically, because the data I connect to does not have a schema... unfortunately !

Comment: they have a loop (actually 3 kinds of) where you can plug your callback, and you can ask for a 'field' and they will answer you with 'response' whihc contains bunch of 'stuff'. I know... :)

Comment: the software in question is a little hack made by the mayor of new york

Comment: it is not just merely dynamically typed : it is *anti-statically typed*

Comment: Just use a `Dictionary<>` and be done with it.

Comment: I agree with @ildjarn, but also note that you could define operators `(?)` and `(?<-)` to make using a dictionary more pleasant syntactically.  These would allow you to write something like `myDict?field1 <- value` rather than using the slightly more cumbersome indexer on the dictionary.

Comment: @ildjam indeed, but I am writing an API so might be worth the look. and now it itches. That said, since MSFT lacks execution levels and therefore makes no use of "runtime type", I will go the Type Provider way, so it might be all wasted in the end.

Comment: @nicolas "anti-statically typed"?  I'd love to see a blog post to explain that term :-) Seriously though it sounds like a type provider would be practically ideal for what you want.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I wonder to what extent they do this to protect their turf. when you think about it, types makes it so much easier to build intelligence outside your environment, which they don't want. anyway, I am crafting a type provider around it, and after I am done, the next step is to provide "reactive" computation unifying all those data (that is historical, real time etc..) under one unmbrella.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting aside the usefulness of the end result, a snippet below achieves exactly what you asked for in the spirit of [my other related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9967890/917053):

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\FSharp.Compiler.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-1.9.9.9\bin\FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll"
#endif

open System 
open System.CodeDom.Compiler 
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type RecordTypeMaker (typeName: string, records: (string*string) []) = 
    let _typeDllName = "Synth"+typeName+".dll"
    let _code = 
        let fsCode = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
        fsCode.Append("module ").Append(typeName).Append(".Code\ntype ").Append(typeName).Append(" = {") |> ignore
        for rec' in records do fsCode.Append("  ").Append(fst rec').Append(" : ").Append(snd rec').Append(";\n") |> ignore
        fsCode.Append("}").ToString()
    let _compiled =
        use provider = new FSharpCodeProvider() 
        let options = CompilerParameters([||], _typeDllName) 
        let result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource( options, [|_code|] ) 
        result.Errors.Count = 0
    let mutable _type: Type = null

    member __.RecordType
        with get() = if _compiled && _type = null then
                         _type <- Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(_typeDllName).GetType(typeName+".Code+"+typeName)
                     _type
```

A sketch implementation of `RecordTypeMaker` accepts an arbitrary `Record type` definition containing `type name` and array of `field names` accompanied by `field type names`. Then behind the curtain it assembles a piece of F# code defining the requested Record type, compiles this code via `CodeDom provider`, loads container assembly and provides access to this newly created synthetic Record type via Reflection. A test snippet

```
let myType = RecordTypeMaker("Test", [|("Field1", "string"); ("Field2", "int")|]).RecordType
printfn "IsRecordType=%b" (FSharpType.IsRecord(myType))
printfn "Record fields: %A" (FSharpType.GetRecordFields(myType))
```

demonstrates for a purely synthetic type `myType` the proof of concept:

```
IsRecordType=true
Record fields: [|System.String Field1; Int32 Field2|]
```

Comment: pretty cool. I am famazed though, I was doing the same fancy pants tricks in 2005 in csharp to get dynamic linq queries. 7 years later, we are almost in the same place wrt composable type creation...

Comment: @nicolas : F# and C# are _statically typed languages_. Runtime type creation is not straightforward or built-in for a reason.

Comment: @ildjam actually the notion of static/dynamic type is incomplete. one need to say static/dynamic in the eye of who. so the 2 notions are very porous in themselves.

Comment: @ildjarn You are totally right, but this is a truism. I am surprised this (convenient) myth of static types has evolved so little in the direction of reality.