# Creating an F# record or union type (not instance thereof) at runtime

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

What is the best way to create an instance of System.Type representing an F# record or union at runtime? That is, I am looking for an equivalent of FSharpType.MakeTupleType for records and unions.

Just to clarify, I am not interested in creating an instance (i.e. FSharpValue.MakeRecord or FSharpValue.MakeUnion).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating F# record through reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139223/creating-f-record-through-reflection)

Comment: @daniel the example given below is actually complete and a useful starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of an equivalent to [FSharpType.MakeTupleType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370461.aspx) for records and unions in the F# library.

One way to create record or union type like structures at runtime is to use [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx). A record type is analogous to a sealed class and a union type is an abstract base class with sealed classes for each case.

For example the following function generates a minimal F# record type:

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Reflection.Emit

let MakeRecord(typeName:string, fields:(string * Type)[]) =
    let name = "GeneratedAssembly"
    let domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    let assembly = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(AssemblyName(name), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave)
    let name = "GeneratedModule"
    let dm = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name, name+".dll")
    let attributes = TypeAttributes.Public ||| TypeAttributes.Class ||| TypeAttributes.Sealed
    let typeBuilder = dm.DefineType(typeName, attributes)
    let con = typeof<CompilationMappingAttribute>.GetConstructor([|typeof<SourceConstructFlags>|])
    let customBuilder = CustomAttributeBuilder(con, [|SourceConstructFlags.RecordType|])
    typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(customBuilder)
    let makeField name t =
        let attributes = FieldAttributes.Assembly
        let fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(name+"@", t, attributes)
        let attributes = PropertyAttributes.None
        let propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(name, attributes, t, [||])
        let customBuilder = CustomAttributeBuilder(con, [|SourceConstructFlags.Field|])
        propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(customBuilder)
        let attributes = MethodAttributes.Public ||| MethodAttributes.HideBySig ||| MethodAttributes.SpecialName
        let methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_"+name, attributes, t, [||])
        let il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator()
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(methodBuilder)
        fieldBuilder
    let types = fields |> Array.map snd
    let cb = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, types)
    let il = cb.GetILGenerator()
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof<obj>.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes))
    fields |> Array.iteri (fun i (name, t) -> 
        let paramName = name.Substring(0,1).ToLower()+name.Substring(1)
        let param = cb.DefineParameter(i+1, ParameterAttributes.In, paramName)
        let fieldBuilder = makeField name t
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, param.Position)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder)
    )
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
    let t = typeBuilder.CreateType()
    assembly.Save("GeneratedModule.dll")
    t

let r = MakeRecord("MyRecord", [|"Alpha",typeof<int>;"Beta",typeof<string>|])
```

Note the expected interfaces for a Record type may also need to be generated, i.e. implementations of IEquatable, IStructuralEquatable, IComparable and IStructuralComparable are missing.

**Update**

Extension methods MakeTupleType and MakeUnionType based on the code sample above are now available in the open source [Fil](https://fil.codeplex.com/) (F# to IL Compiler) project (alpha).

Comment: CodePlex is shutting down, this answer links to that for `Fil`, is there a new repo?